# Visual Studio Code cannot fin Git-bash

Tags: visual-studio-code, git-bash

I want to add git-bash to Visual Studio Code.

In the normal Terminal I can type `where.exe git` and `git --version`.
It shows me the right output.

But when I try to open a default shell in visual studio code it can not find the `git` terminal.

So I have added some additional variables to the path.
The `git.exe` and the `cmd\git.exe` are there.
Additionally, I tried to add the paths to the `.json` file in Visual Studio Code.

Nothing worked.

My last try was to add the `mintyy.exe` to the `.json` file.
This gave me the code down below as output.
In an external mintty terminal:

```
 rev-parse: Exit 126.
 Failed to run 'rev-parse': No such file or directory
```

Here I had no choice to open the mintty terminal, it has just opened.
What can I try next?

Answer (score 0):

Open your user setting, and edit "`git.path`"

It should reference the full path of `git.exe`.

For instance, I have:

```
"git.path": "c:\\Public\\gits\\latest\\bin\\git.exe"
```

Then, in the default terminal, I get:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Tous droits réservés.

PS C:\Users\VonC\> git --version
git version 2.23.0.windows.1
PS C:\Users\VonC\>
```